# Can't create new category and product - Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'entity_id' cannot be null

Tags: magento2, product, category

I've been working with magento for a month now and everything working fine so far. Due to circumstances I need to move magento to another machine. Again everything are working properly after I move it. But then when I want to create new category and products I received the below error. I don't think that moving magento was the main cause. I'm using magento version 2.2.4.

**Error received when saving new category**

[image: adding category error]

**Error received when saving new simple products**

[image: Adding simple products error]

**Exception log (after saving new category):**

```
*main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'entity_id' cannot be null, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `parent_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `path`, `position`, `level`, `children_count`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'entity_id' cannot be null, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `parent_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `path`, `position`, `level`, `children_count`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) at magento\\vendor\\magento\\zendframework1\\library\\Zend\\Db\\Statement\\Pdo.php:235, PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'entity_id' cannot be null at magento\\vendor\\magento\\zendframework1\\library\\Zend\\Db\\Statement\\Pdo.php:228)"} []*
```

**Exception log (after saving new simple products):**

```
*main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'entity_id' cannot be null, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `type_id`, `sku`, `has_options`, `required_options`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'entity_id' cannot be null, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `type_id`, `sku`, `has_options`, `required_options`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) at magento\\vendor\\magento\\zendframework1\\library\\Zend\\Db\\Statement\\Pdo.php:235, PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'entity_id' cannot be null at magento\\vendor\\magento\\zendframework1\\library\\Zend\\Db\\Statement\\Pdo.php:228)"} []*
```

From the exception log, magento was failing due to `entity_id`.

Do you know what's causing and how to solve the issue? Updating existing products are working fine. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just got that problem and it was because I forgot I had disabled some module in my new environment. You should take a look at that. Personally I had disabled a lot of Magento staging module from the EE edition.

Comment: Hey! Right now, only a theme was installed to my site and I tried to install it (the theme) to a fresh install magento and saving new products/category works just fine. Before I installed quite a few free extensions that wasn't compatible with the magento at all and so I remove it, maybe that's the cause? Im using CE.